# How to copy object to different amazon account using aws sdk v2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am working on java project in which I am using aws sdk v2 for using amazon s3 services .
I am performing copy operation it is working with same account but not working with different account.

**Code :-**

```
     public void copyObjects(S3Object[] s3DestObjects, String sDestBucket, String sSourceBucket, String sSourceObject) {
        try {
    AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    ACCESS_KEY,
                    SECRET_KEY);
            S3ClientBuilder s3ClientBuilder = 
        S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds));
            
                s3ClientBuilder.region(Region.US_EAST_2);
            
            S3Client s3Client = s3ClientBuilder.build();
            String encodedUrl = null;
            try {
                encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(sSourceBucket + "/" + sSourceObject, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println("URL could not be encoded: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            for (S3Object s3DestObject : s3DestObjects) {

                //CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = CopyObjectRequest.builder().destinationBucket(dstBucket).destinationKey(dstS3Object.key).copySource(encodedUrl).build();
                CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
                        .copySource(encodedUrl)
                        .destinationBucket(sDestBucket)
                        .destinationKey(s3DestObject.key)
                        .metadata(s3DestObject.getMetadata()).metadataDirective(MetadataDirective.REPLACE)
                        .build();
                CopyObjectResponse copyObjectResponse = s3Client.copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
            }
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This above code is working with same account bucket but not working with different account bucket and getting error :-

```
 Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 4VCND27Z6P3CEJ8H, Extended Request ID: 2T88jx4+R+LjO74pBHOhJj8uOUx6M4Hx3UYYkWm4Sbf6cb9NVM8f5DvFcanv0rbXhZUfEkqpSuI=)
```

please suggest how can i do copy objects to different accounts?

Answer (score 2):

It appears your situation is:

- You have Amazon S3 buckets in different AWS Accounts
- You wish to copy objects between the buckets

There are two ways to do this:

**1. 'Push' the objects**

If your code is running in Account A and you wish to copy from a bucket in Account A to a bucket in Account B, then you will need:

- Permission on the IAM Entity (eg IAM User or IAM Role) that is being used by your program to **write to** the bucket in Account B, *AND*
- A **bucket policy** on the bucket in Account B that permits the IAM Entity used by your program to **write to** the bucket
- When copying the object, you must set `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` to 'hand-over' ownership of the object to the destination AWS Account

*OR*

**2. 'Pull' the objects**

If your code is running in Account B and you wish to copy from a bucket in Account A to a bucket in Account B, then you will need:

- Permission on the IAM Entity (eg IAM User or IAM Role) that is being used by your program to **read from** the bucket in Account A, *AND*
- A **bucket policy** on the bucket in Account A that permits the IAM Entity used by your program to **read from** the bucket

Note that in both cases, your program needs permission from the AWS Account it is running in *AND* a bucket policy on the bucket in the other AWS Account.

Comment: Hi, I have a different use case where the code is running in account A, I put an object in account B, and then I would like to copy the same object in account C. is this possible ? we are using service account in kubernetes

Comment: @akaliza Using credentials from a third account is effectively a mix of the above two options. You will need a Bucket Policy on the source bucket that allows `GetObject` for the credentials being used, and another Bucket Policy on the destination bucket that allows `PutObject` for the credentials being used. Feel free to create a new Question if you have difficulties.